# NuGet update, now throwing OpenTok: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly JWT Version=2.0.0.0 on CreateSession

Tags: c#, jwt, opentok

I just updated all my NuGet packages and I can no longer connect to a session.  I'm running OpenTok 3.1.0 and JWT 6.1.0 but getting the following error on OpenTok.ConnectSession:

```
OpenTok = new OpenTok(apiKey, apiSecret);
SessionHost = OpenTok.CreateSession(mediaMode: MediaMode.ROUTED);   <-- error here

3/1/2020 7:40:08 AM ERROR:
OpenTok: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'JWT, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'JWT, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at OpenTokSDK.Util.HttpClient.GenerateJwt(Int32 key, String secret, Int32 expiryPeriod)
   at OpenTokSDK.Util.HttpClient.GetCommonHeaders()
   at OpenTokSDK.Util.HttpClient.GetRequestHeaders(Dictionary`2 headers)
   at OpenTokSDK.Util.HttpClient.DoRequest(String url, Dictionary`2 specificHeaders, Dictionary`2 bodyData)
   at OpenTokSDK.OpenTok.CreateSession(String location, MediaMode mediaMode, ArchiveMode archiveMode)
   at eTutorServer.eTutorService.userIdentification(Int32 handle, String strData, String[] sAry) in D:\Data\CADE.Net\eTutorServer\eTutorServer\eTutorService.cs:line 1514

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = JWT, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/Data/CADE.Net/eTutorServer/eTutorServer/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : OpenTok, Version=3.1.6873.25151, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\Data\CADE.Net\eTutorServer\eTutorServer\bin\Debug\eTutorServer.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Data/CADE.Net/eTutorServer/eTutorServer/bin/Debug/JWT.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: PUBLIC KEY TOKEN
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

It appears that I might have a JWT versioning problem since it references 2.0.0.0 in the error message while I have 6.1.0 installed and in packages.config.  However, I don't know why it would show 2.0.0.0 or how to fix that.

Comment: The version number only gets updated when the compile recognizes the Net library has changed.  The VS update process is not very robust and often error like this occur when the update doesn't find the object.  Easiest way is in Solution Explorer delete the object and the add again.  Adding will get latest version of object.  You can open the csproj file in Notepad and make the edit.

Comment: Interesting... I uninstalled JWT and OpenTok, reinstalled OpenTok and JWT 2.3.1 was installed.  I tried it and it worked.  I installed JWT 6.1.0 and it failed.  Tried some other versions but it looked like 3.1.1 was the latest that worked.  Sounds like I need to take this up with the OpenTok guys...  Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jdweng's comments led directly to the answer.  OpenTok doesn't work with 6.1.0, uninstalling fixed the issue.  Have since posted an issue with TokBox to find out why it doesn't work.